# Why DataGridComboBoxColumn CellStyle won't apply padding

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.6.1

Some days I really regret ever going down the route of using WPF for an application...

I am trying to use `DataGridComboBoxColumn` and all I want to do is apply padding to the text in the cell when it is not being edited but it seems they made that an impossible task

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Statuses" Source="{Binding Path=Statuses}" />        
</Window.Resources>

<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Status"
                        Width="100"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Statuses}}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                        SelectedValuePath="Index"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Status}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,2" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

I tried setting `ElementStyle` and overriding the `Template` but this just causes some weird validation error and after a quick internet search it seems this is a bad option to take.

I then resorted to using a DataGridTemplateColumn but this leaves me trying to convert my Binding Value back into the same text as the ComboBox `DisplayMemberPath` and my attempt at using a `ValueConverter` failed as it never passed a value from my CollectionViewSource "Statuses".

Now I have run out of patience and will just have to accept that I can't style these cells, unless someone out there has a quick and reliable fix for this?

**Edit**: I have created a [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/glrad/DataGridComboBoxStyling) with an example of what I am trying to do, there is also a branch named 'value-converter' with my failed attempt at implementing `IValueConverter` and using `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is probably to define a custom `ComboBoxColumn` and set the `Margin` property of the element generated in the `GenerateElement` method:

```
public class CustomComboBoxColumn : System.Windows.Controls.DataGridComboBoxColumn
{
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
        if (fe is Control control)
            control.Margin = new Thickness(4, 2, 4, 2);
        return fe;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<local:CustomComboBoxColumn Header="Status"
                                    Width="100"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Statuses}}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                    SelectedValuePath="Index"
                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Status}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting Margin for the ElementStyle?

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```